# Legacy Installed Application Classpath Fiasco

Tags: java, weblogic, classpath, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

#### Massively messed up production issue:

I have inherited a massive ( 1 million line code base ) web application that my predecessors botched up completely.

They thought it would be a wonderful idea to just add the `WEB-INF/classes` directory the the `system classpath` in the `startupWeblogic` script instead of properly packaging up the application in an `ear` or `war` file, and manually point all the paths in the console to the various non-standard paths they just conceived of themselves.

Now my problem is I have to install another application as a proper `war` file that uses classes with the same packages and names, just even older code, into the same **Weblogic 10.3.6** instances. But as you can imagine the stuff that is hacked into the `system classpath` takes precedence over everything in the additional webapp, even with the `prefer web app lib` preference set in the `weblogic.xml` file.

#### Notes:

Repackaging the offending application is **not** an option on my timeline, *it is going to be done, but just not in the timeline I have to meet*. Running on other instances of Weblogic isn't in my timeline either, I don't have the time to go through the provisioning process to get the assets in time.

Given this how can I get this additional webapp to play nice and deploy in the same weblogic instance as the one that is hacked into the `system classpath`.

*If someone can give me an answer that solves this issue, I will make sure to put a massive bounty on this when I am able to and award it to you after the fact. The sooner the answer the bigger the bounty will be!*

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `prefer-application-packages` within the `weblogic-application.xml` as well?

The mechanism that Weblogic calls the Filtering Classloader, here are the links:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html#wp1097187

http://hasamali.blogspot.in/2011/08/weblogic-identifying-class-conflict-and.html

http://atheek.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/weblogic-filtering-classloaders/

Comment: yes thanks I tried that and it isn't working either. even though you should be able to put something before the `system classpath` we can't get it to accept the configuration, thanks for the links and any other suggestions.